# Vayne evergized attack with no items

Tags: league-of-legends

I played vayne recently and I noticed at lvl 1, with no items (other than starting items) she had an energized buff very similar with that of static shiv and rfc. The description said just "energized attack" and the effect I observed was a brief movement speed increase when attacking with 100 stacks. What is the source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Warlords Bloodlust](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warlord's_Bloodlust) got reworked. The effect now is:

> Moving or attacking makes an attack Energized. Energized attacks grant
>   1% - 50% (based on level) lifesteal and 30% movement speed for 0.75
>   seconds.

Comment: and they forgot to update the description... ?

Comment: @bolov Apparently yes they forgot to upgrade the tooltip. But it's in the [official patch notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-75-notes#patch-masteries)

Comment: @bolov I just tested it and I can confirm that the tooltip isn't upgraded in neither the client or the game but the mastery works as described in the patch notes.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this was changed. I may need to rethink whether I still want to use it.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yeah it's kinda hidden. Especially since they forgot to update the tooltips. Right now the only way of finding out is through external websites.